# Input field css issue - works in chrome/ff etc but not IE

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have this input field that works fine on chrome and firefox:

[image]

but not on IE - it looks like this:

[image]

And like this when I click the field:

[image]

Here's the css for the input type being used:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select, checkbox, radio {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #777;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: normal;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.5s, border ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.5s, border ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.5s, border ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.5s, border ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

Any thoughts how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a background-color: white; to the css for the input element.

Comment: It didn't make any difference Louis. The results are exactly the same.